# Improving memory management in a Net Core Windows-Service

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, .net-core

I wanted to ask about the best approach for having a console application which can also be used as a windows-service in a net core environment. The problem is not for having such an application, but rather the executed code.
I try to explain what exactly my problem is.

If the windows-service is started, a for-loop is being initiated which does several things

- accessing amazons AWS SQS
- accesing via HTTP-Request a csv-file => those data is being used and partially stored in a db
- accessing tables of an oracle db via EF (insert,update and delete)

So far so good. Everything is working out as I want to. Using dependency injection (Scoped) for accessing in my loop those methods I have programmed for getting all the action done.

The tricky part is that the memory usage of this application is rather ... not optimal. It does what it does, but while downloading and using the data of the csv files, the application uses too much memory and doesn't free up properly. Do you have any suggestions or knowlegde base articles how to handle such scenarios (loop in windows-service)?

I tried to free up everything I can, like clearing lists and setting them to null, disabled any tracking in EF while querying data (also disabled extra insert / update changetracker) and using "using statements" ( / disposing elements).

Also, I would like to add that I am using the latest SDK of Amazon AWS (Core and SQS) and EF Core 2.2.6 with Oracle Provider.

Any chance you might have a hint?

If you need more information, just tell me. I will then provide more data as needed.

Kind regards

---

Regarding the comment of reading csv file

Reading the file from the URL.

```
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                await using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        var content = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                        result.Content = content.Split('\n').ToList();

                        result.IsSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and after reading it, I convert it to my target class

```
public static async Task<List<Curve>> ReturnCurveData(List<string> content)
    {
        var checkVar = -1;
        var list = new List<Curve>();

        foreach (var entry in content)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry)) continue;

            var entrySplitted = entry.Split('|');
            if (entrySplitted.Length < 3) continue;
            else if(!int.TryParse(entrySplitted[0], out checkVar)) continue;

            var item = new Curve();
            item.Property1 = Convert.ToInt32(entrySplitted[0]);
            item.Property2 = (entrySplitted.Length ==3) ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(entrySplitted[1]);
            item.Property3 = (entrySplitted.Length ==3) ? Convert.ToDateTime(entrySplitted[1]) : Convert.ToDateTime(entrySplitted[2]);
            item.Value = (entrySplitted.Length ==3) ? Convert.ToDecimal(entrySplitted[2], new CultureInfo("en-US")): Convert.ToDecimal(entrySplitted[3], new CultureInfo("en-US"));

            list.Add(item);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(list);
    }
```

---

Regarding the definition of scope

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                ...
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<Data.Queries.Database.Db>();
                services.AddScoped<Data.Queries.External.Aws>();
                services.AddScoped<Data.Queries.External.Web>();
                services.RegisterEfCoreOracle<DbContext>(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                    "cfg_db.json");
                services.AddScoped<IExecute, Execute>();
                services.AddHostedService<ExecuteHost>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                ...
            });

public static void RegisterEfCoreOracle<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string configurationDirectory, string configurationFile, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where T : DbContext
    {
        //Adding configuration file
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(configurationDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile(configurationFile, optional: false)
            .Build();

        services.Configure<OracleConfiguration<T>>(configuration);

        var oraConfig = services.ReturnServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<OracleConfiguration<T>>>();

        if (oraConfig.Value.Compatibility != null)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<T>(o => o
                .UseOracle(oraConfig.Value.ConnectionString(), b => b
                    .UseOracleSQLCompatibility(oraConfig.Value.Compatibility)), lifetime);
        }

        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<T>(o => o
                .UseOracle(oraConfig.Value.ConnectionString()), lifetime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're loading the whole .csv file in memory, which you should never do. Hard to tell without code or profiling support though.

Comment: agree with this comment. You should use a Stream if possible. However if you can't do that, you could deallocate the object and force GC. Don't see why you couldn't stream though

Comment: i updated my initial post. Maybe you can tell how you would do it differently if it is from your persepctive not the best approach? @Blindy

Comment: How are you defining a Scope?  You don't want to keep a single EF DbContext around for very long.  ASP.NET does this for you by defining Scopes for each request.  But in a long-running service you either have to create your own scopes, or manage the lifecycle of the DbContext manually.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i edited my original post. I hope this clarifies what I meant with "Scope".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you posted your code, we can analyze the problem pretty easily:

```
var content = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

As I said, never read the file in memory, process it line by line, for example using a `StreamReader` or `StringReader`, or any of the million csv parsers in Nuget.

```
 result.Content = content.Split('\n').ToList();
```

Not only are you reading the entire file in memory, you're then splitting it into values (so *in addition to the entire file contents*, you're allocating an array of length equal to the number of lines, and for each line allocating strings for each element that's separated by a comma, for a total of lines*elements strings), and *in addition to all that* allocating yet another list and copying the contents of the array into it.

Edit: You're splitting it into lines here, and into values in the second part. My analysis is correct, but the problem is split over multiple lines.

Needless to say this is ludicrous at best. Stop using `Split`, don't `ToList` needlessly, and don't read all of it at once. You're writing a web server, all of this could theoretically be done once for each request processed, which can easily go in the dozens depending on your CPU.

I won't go over the second part, but it's even worse. At a glance I see even more lists allocated and even more `Split`s. And the line `return await Task.FromResult(list);` shows you don't understand async funtions at all. Not only what you have is not async at all, but if you insist on making it async for the fun of it, return the list directly, not as an awaited task.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive comment. I will work on this. I am missing somekind of reflection on about what and how I am implementing my application. So, every feedback is welcome which leads me to further improvement and understanding of working with c#.

Comment: We all gotta start somewhere!

Comment: One more quick comment, never use `decimal` without a really really good reason. I can tell you from direct experience working with Boeing that `float` is not enough to represent a point on this planet (ie a plane) accurately, but `double` is completely stable. I can't think of something needing more precision than a commercial plane's auto-pilot software.

Comment: Thank you. I will remember that. :-)